# How to add Scrollbar to the Mainwindow using Perl TK

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I want to add scroll bar in my main window. How can I add scroll bar in my main window. Please  help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TK you wouldn't add a scrollbar to the main window, but you create a widget to be scrolled and add scroll bars to scroll it.
This is a little complex to do your self so TK has some helpers to make it easier.

[TK::Pane](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.028/Tk/Pane.pm) can be used to create an empty scrolled container that you can add other widgets to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Tk::Pane or you can use the [Scrolled constructor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk::Scrolled) to create a scrolled Frame or other widget.

```
my $f = $mw->Scrolled( Frame => @frame_options );
```